# Toggle Visibility of Expander icon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

Hi I'm using XAML and C# to create a simple WPF demo. I want to toggle the visibility of just the arrow button of the expander. I've edited a custom template for the expander as seen below in the xaml code. I know I have to change the visibility of the ellipse and path.

```
  <Window x:Class="expander.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF000000"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF000000"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF707070"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF333333"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF333333"/>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    <TransformCollection>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                                    </TransformCollection>
                                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    <TransformCollection>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                                    </TransformCollection>
                                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    <TransformCollection>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                    </TransformCollection>
                                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave">
            <Expander Header="Expander" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle1}">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </Expander>

        </Grid>
    </Window>

private void Grid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

How would I access the ellipse and path in the above functions. I tried doing "this.expander.circle" but it doesn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to inspect visual tree to get arrow button. Also you can create custom control and use ApplyTemplate event to extract arrow.

Comment: When do you need to change the visibility? Is an attached property an option?

Comment: You can try using Relativesource concept of XAML

Comment: I want to change the visibility upon the mouse entering and leaving the main grid. For example, the icon is hidden until they enter the grid. It'll then disappear once the mouse leaves the grid and so on. This is similar to an article on news.google.com